# PyQt: QListView in connection with QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a QListView and a QTextEdit on a form and I would like to get them working together, as follows: if a checkbox is checked, the index of the respective item in the QlistView should be displayed in tbe QTextEdit; if the checkbox is unchecked, the value should be deleted from the QTextEdit. The indexes should be displayed cumulatively, delimited by one character (say, a comma), eg., 0,1,3.

Conversely, if a value is typed in the the QTextEdit, the respective checkbox should be automatically checked (or none, in case the value entered does not correspond to any index in the QListView).

<del>I attempted to catch the indices of the selected checboxes by attaching an handler to the clicked event of the QListView, as below:</del>

```
<del>@QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def onclick(self, index):
        editbox.setText(str(index.row()))</del>
```

<del>but got the error message: "NameError: global name 'self' is not defined".</del>

Any hints? Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide!

Here is my complete test code:

EDIT: I changed the code below to deal properly with event handlers.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import Qt, QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        for n in range(10):                   
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem('Item %s' % n)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            model.appendRow(item)

        listview = QtGui.QListView()
        listview.setModel(model)
        listview.clicked.connect(self.onclick)

        self.editbox = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.editbox.textChanged.connect(self.onchange)

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setRowStretch(0, 6)
        grid.setRowStretch(1, 4)
        grid.addWidget(listview)
        grid.setSpacing(2)
        grid.addWidget(self.editbox)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setGeometry(300, 150, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")
        self.show()

    #@QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def onclick(self, index):
        self.editbox.append(str(index.row()))

    def onchange(self):
        print "text in edit box changed"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're defining `onclick` outside of a class definition, there's no `self` (which refers to an instance of the class) either. Define it as a regular function instead:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
def onclick(index):
    editbox.setText(str(index.row()))
```

and connect it to the signal as `listview.clicked.connect(onclick)`.